# Why is match a keyword and not a function in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I don't see why Scala has `match` defined as a keyword instead of a function. It could be defined through implicits (like `ArrowAssoc`). For example, consider the following.

```
  implicit class Matchy[A](a: A) {

    def matchy[T](pf: PartialFunction[A, T]): T = pf(a)
  }

  val myVar = 10
  val myString = myVar matchy {
    case 5 => "five"
    case 10 => "ten"
    case x => x.toString
  }

  println(myString) // Prints "ten".
```

This would free up match as a variable name and hint to the fact that `case` can be used outside of match blocks.

So why does Scala define `match` as a keyword?

Comment: maybe we don't want to manually `import` this implicit :)

Comment: @chengpohi It could be included in Predef. You don't have to import ArrowAssoc do you?

Comment: but the scala library also is using `match` keyword....

Comment: @chengpohi What do you mean?

Comment: Since scala use the previous scala library to develop, but in scala library is using the **match** keyword to develop library, if you want to change `match` keyword to the `implicit` in `Predef`, so you need to change the previous version, if you change it in previous version, there will be both `match` in library(for compatible): `keyword` and `implicit`. this will cause confusion, Does it make sense?

Comment: @chengpohi; I don't think the question is "why don't they change `match` to a function" but "why didn't they use a function in the first place".

Comment: A `PartialFunctionK` using the *case* matches is created using *pattern matching* syntax, see: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html. If you didn't have pattern matching, you wouldn't be able to create a partial function as you did, it's the chicken and egg problem.

Comment: OK, that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You don't want to create a `PartialFunction` and have a function call each time for such a fundamental operation.
2. Tail calls in `match` become non-tail-calls in `matchy`.
3. This is exactly the kind of megamorphic call JITs have trouble inlining. `matchy` could be made explicitly `@inline` though.
4. In general, you lose a *lot* of optimization opportunities.

Probably more reasons I am missing...